How to deal with multiple migration paths in Entity Framework
I'd like to be able to use Entity Framework for a project I'm working on, but I have an interesting use case I need to support.
Let's say each of these minor releases also includes schema changes which are managed with Entity Framework. Moving from 1.x to 1.y is very straightforward.
As shown here, I have two branches with each node representing a release with schema changes. A customer might be on 1.1 and we've made some hotfixes for that version. At the same time, development is continued on the main branch and includes those same changes (e.g. 1.2 and 1.3).
Is there a way for EF to migrate from say 1.1.2 to 1.4 and skip migrations 1.2 and 1.3 which would cause an error because they have the same schema changes as in the hotfixes?


For a start, hotfixes should never involve something as consequential as a schema change.  I mean if clients are running 1.2, 1.3, ... without consequences what would justify schema changes to be applied to 1.1?
If there were a scenario where a client on an old version encountered a problem that involved a schema change and I was using code-first (which I honestly avoid) I would not attempt to fix it with a migration on that old release branch. I would make the changes on Trunk and the client would get the fix when they upgrade.

As for if you really had to do it and you apply an alternate migration on a database versioned to 1.1 to a Migration 1.1.2  and you also fix the issue in Migration 1.4 which is the latest Trunk release version, when a client wants to move from 1.1.2 to 1.4 then you might need to consider having a reversion migration and a script to wipe both the 1.1.2 migration and the reversion migration from the database migration history before the migrations for 1.2, 1.3, etc. all run.
